# How do you track how many sites have an actively embedded iframe widget?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, analytics, http-referer

I have an iframe widget that is being embedded in over 3000 third party sites, but I want to know exactly how many sites it is embedded in.

Our current method is to use google analytics to generate a list of referers, and have a script manually curl each url in the list to look for our widget.

Another method we were thinking of is to use php to print a $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], and use javascript to fire an analytics event if it determines the page is in an iframe, but as the referer can be manipulated, I don't know how effective it would be.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would someone manipulate the referrer?

Comment: Say a competitor would want to manipulate our metrics. They could easily write a script to continuously load our page with different referer's, giving us false positives. Unlikely, but still a possibility.